# How to actually connect things in a webapp

Tags: java, tomcat

This might be a very stupid question, but I'm entirely new to web programming, and the internet has proven unusually unhelpful in this area...

### My Background (not technically necessary to read; although the question's probably easier to answer with this than without):

I'm very comfortable with Java, and use Eclipse for the vast majority of my work. I feel pretty confidant that I can do, or easily figure out how to do, anything I want to be able to do in MySQL, HTML, and CSS. And, while I haven't done much JavaScript, I'm not particularly intimidated by it.

I have an Apache Tomcat server, and have edited the default JSP to show what I want it to show, and I'm sure I could write the JavaScript to get the form on it to post back to the server, but my issue is that I don't know how to get the server to receive the form information, or how to get it to serve a page in response. I also don't know how to get it to communicate with the database. While I have a little experience with network programming at the socket level, this... isn't that.

There are resources on the internet that come tantalizingly close to helping me figure out how to actually get done what I want to get done (I've heard good things about Jetty and Tapestry), but the wall I keep running into is that there don't seem to be any tutorials on this, and those tutorials which do exist tend to gloss over stuff at my current level because they assume anyone reading their documentation has already written a webapp.

(I've read many of the official Java Tutorials; this is strangely enough a subject skipped over. So, I can write an applet or a webstart application, but...)

### My Question(s):

How can I get my Tomcat server to communicate with a database, and manipulate HTTP POSTs and GETs from the user?
Does anyone know any tutorials that are both clear and in-depth about the subject of writing web applications?

Comment: This is not something anyone can explain it to you as a stackoverflow answer...because it took me one whole semester leaner this :) 4 months! but try looking for book for JavaEE

Comment: you can also try w3schools . you will get pretty simple and easy to learn 1 page articles. If you want to dig deep then check a book for Servlets, Oreilly has a good book though.

Comment: Tomcat is a servlet container which handles your request. The people here on SO have put together a small article on the lifecycle of the servlet, how to handle the form input etc. You can find it here http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find this one quite good

http://www.servletworld.com/servlet-tutorials/j2ee-web-development-overview.html